# Подскажите пожалуйста, как решить проблему с переходом на новую активность в Android?

Tags: java, android

У меня две активности: MainActivity и CategoriesActivity. На первой есть 2 кнопки (обычные button), одна из которых ведет на вторую активность (CategoriesActivity). Всё стандартное, исключая текст на кнопках (первая активность) и задний фон все на той же первой активности, при попытке запустить приложение  работает, а при переходе на новую активность, то есть нажимаю на кнопку вылетает приложение с ошибкой (в приложении произошел сбой).

Может, кто-нибудь знает, как решить проблему?

MainActivity.java

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private List<Slide> IstSlides ;
    private ViewPager sliderpager;
    private Button startBtn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        sliderpager = findViewById(R.id.slider_pager);
         startBtn = findViewById(R.id.start_btn);

        startBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                try {

                    Intent categoryIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CategoriesActivity.class);
                    startActivity(categoryIntent);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        });


        // Список слайдов
        IstSlides = new ArrayList<>();
        IstSlides.add(new Slide(R.drawable.slide1, ""));
        IstSlides.add(new Slide(R.drawable.slide1, ""));

        SliderPagerAdapter adapter = new SliderPagerAdapter(this, IstSlides);
        sliderpager.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
```

CategoriesActivity.java

```
import android.view.MenuItem;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class CategoriesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_categories);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        setSupportActionBar (toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Categories");
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rv);

        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        layoutManager.setOrientation(RecyclerView.VERTICAL);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        List<CategoryModel> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new CategoryModel("", "Category1"));
        list.add(new CategoryModel("", "Category1"));
        list.add(new CategoryModel("", "Category1"));
        list.add(new CategoryModel("", "Category1"));
        list.add(new CategoryModel("", "Category1"));
        list.add(new CategoryModel("", "Category1"));
        list.add(new CategoryModel("", "Category1"));
        list.add(new CategoryModel("", "Category1"));
        list.add(new CategoryModel("", "Category1"));
        list.add(new CategoryModel("", "Category1"));

        CategoryAdapter adapter = new CategoryAdapter(list);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }




    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
            finish();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: приложите лог ошибки пожалуйста к вопросу

Comment: лог ошибки к вопросу приложил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как уже было сказано в ответе [@SergeiBuvaka](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/288062/sergei-buvaka) вам нужно установить определенную тему для вашего приложения. Но я бы так же предложил, добавить свои стили для вашей активности в которой будет ваш тулбар:

```
 <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
               <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
               <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
            </style>
```

в то время как ваши основные стили будут с тулбаром:

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

и дальше в манифесте установим тему для активности которую вы хотите сделать без тулбара:

```
<activity

android:name="com.example.NonActionBarActivity"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
```

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего ваша проблема в установленной теме. Вы пытаетесь установить свой `ActionBar` в то время как в теме он уже прописан. Вам необходимо установить родительскую тему

```
Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar
```

Либо другие в которых по дефолту нет `ActionBar`.